# opening a page after another with curl

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I want to open a page from a site and save the cookies. Then open another page with those cookies.(It doesn't let me to visit the second page without the first page's cookies)
I tried this code but it didn't work.

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cook.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cook.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'url');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_exec($ch);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'nexturl');
    $rs = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $rs;
```

Answer (score 0):

End of your each curl operation close the curl handle. Otherwise it will not save the cookie into the file.

```
$rs = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Now initiate second curl, and send the request. It should work now.